# why is a function assigned to a class attribute treated as an instance method?

Tags: python, object

I'm trying to program an object that has a `getCallable()` method returning a function. I would like to provide this function as a class attribute, so that I can just inherit my parent class and set a different function to each child class.

In my case, the object is a widget with interactive input fields, that users can fill to set most of the functions parameters.

The problem is that the function seems to be treated as an instance method, the instance is passed as first parameter when it is called.

Why is that? How can I modify my code so that the instance is not passed as function attribute?

Here is a very simplified example that reproduces my issue:

```
def mult(a, b):
    return a * b


class MultiplierFilter(object):
    function = mult

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.multiplier = 1

    def parameters(self):
        return {
            "multiplier": self.multiplier}

    def setParameters(self, params):
        """
        :param dict params:
        :return:
        """
        self.multiplier = params.get("multiplier", 1)

    def getCallable(self):
        """Return a function that takes a number as only argument and returns
        another number.
        """
        mult = self.multiplier

        def f(value):
            return self.function(value, mult)
        return f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiplier_object = MultiplierFilter()
    multiplier_object.setParameters({"multiplier": 2})

    test_function = multiplier_object.getCallable()
    print(test_function(7.))
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pierre/PycharmProjects/pyipsdk_tuto/2.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(test_function(7.))
  File "C:/Users/Pierre/PycharmProjects/pyipsdk_tuto/2.py", line 30, in f
    return self.function(value, mult)
TypeError: mult() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you defined the function; it is simply a function within the namespace of the class at the end of the `class` definition, and therefore is treated like any other function you have defined there. A `class` block is fully functional Python code, the only thing that matters is what the result at the end of the block is.

What you want is to decorate the function with [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class MultiplierFilter:
    function = staticmethod(mult)
```

This will prevent `self` from being passed implicitly at calltime.